# Retrieving values from array throws error javacript

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

**I am having an array with following values:**

```
 [
  {
    'Admin1': {
      id: 'fa1b2731'
     
    },
    'Admin2': {
      id: '7b5ab064'
     
    },
    'Admin3': {
      id: '9f462511'
     
    },
    'Admin4': {
      id: 'aa82421d'
    
    },
    'Admin5': {
      id: '34cb2b'
     
    },
    'Admin6': {
      id: 'ff71ffdd'
    
    },
    'Admin7': {
      id: 'b57ac9e7'    
      
    }
  }
]
```

**The code i am trying to retrieve each user id from above array is throwing an error->expected undefined not to be undefined
Following is the code snippet:**

```
 if (userArray) {    
    for (const user of Object.values(userArray)) {
      const delUserRes = await userApi.deleteUserById({
        token: accessToken,
        organizationId: orgid;,
        userId: user.id
      });
```

**the above method reads the userarray corectly but never assign each id to userId form user.id and throws error**

Comment: Looks like you are getting the values of your array and not the values of each object inside of your array (that is if `userArray` is the array you're showing at the top of your question)

Comment: if `userArray` is an array, theres no reason to use `Object.values`, since it is not an object... go straight with `(const user of userArray){...` But, then you'll have only a single element, this one is the one where you need to use Object.values

Answer (score 1):

The array in example is having one item, what i mean to get `user.id` you should call `array[0].['Admin1'].id`. In your code you doing it like `array.['Admin1'].id`, so thats why it can't find `user.id`.

try something like this

```
 if (userArray) {    
    for (const user of Object.values(userArray[0])) {
      const delUserRes = await userApi.deleteUserById({
        token: accessToken,
        organizationId: orgid;,
        userId: user.id
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your all the user are in single element of array object at 0 index.
try below code

```js
 for (const user of Object.values(userArray[0])) {
console.log(user) 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are trying to get values from an object inside an array, so the `Object.values` doesn't make sense in your code. You can simply use `userArray[0]` in your for loop or `map` like:

```js
var data = [ { 'Admin1': { id: 'fa1b2731' }, 'Admin2': { id: '7b5ab064' }, 'Admin3': { id: '9f462511' }, 'Admin4': { id: 'aa82421d' }, 'Admin5': { id: '34cb2b' }, 'Admin6': { id: 'ff71ffdd' }, 'Admin7': { id: 'b57ac9e7' } } ] 

Object.values(data[0]).map(user => {   //your logic here } );
```